# Are the SGC, IOA, and SGA expedition war criminals?

Tags: stargate

Multiple times in Stargate chemical warfare is used in some fashion. Wouldn't that make these groups war criminals or does it not apply to them?

Comment: Well, they also blew up a sun...

Comment: But blowing up a sun isn't part of the geneva convention rules... or is it?

Comment: Well, other planets aren't part of those convention either.... which probably is the answer, now that I think of it.

Comment: Are you sure? That's part of what I'm questioning... Who can be guilty of a war crime and against who? The SGC may not be because the US isn't a signee of the geneva convention... or whatever it's called when you tentatively agree but won't be held to it since it's used against non-Earth people. On the other hand the SGA expedition would include people that are bound by those laws... but they do it to the Wraith so how does that work?

Comment: We really should put up blowing up a sun in the Geneva convention.  We've only got the one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The very short answer is **no**. Assuming the world of Stargate is similar to our own, neither the Geneva Convention, nor the various acts of international law to which the US is party would cover individuals living on other planets.

The specific preamble in the [Geneva Convention](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/applic/ihl/ihl.nsf/7c4d08d9b287a42141256739003e636b/fe20c3d903ce27e3c125641e004a92f3) is that it only reflects crimes that are...

> *".... committed against **persons or property protected by the Convention:** willful killing, torture or inhuman treatment, including
>   biological experiments, willfully causing great suffering or serious
>   injury to body or health."*".

You may also wish to note that the Convention very specifically relates to **[human persons](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/ihl/COM/380-600037?OpenDocument)**.

> The principle stated in Article 27 [ Link ] of **absolute respect for
>   the human person** might have constituted a sufficient guarantee for
>   protected persons in itself.

Since the Jaffa, nor the Goa'uld (both of whom were subject to chemical attacks by the SGC and IOA) are signatories to the convention, nor considered human by the treaties that forbid action by the use of chemical weapons, nor are the hosts considered to be protected individuals (all parties can be broadly categorised as combatants), both the Jaffa and Goa'uld as well as their hosts and slave armies can be attacked with impunity, at least *as regards prosecution for chemical war crimes*.

Comment: Would things like the symbiote poison be a violation of the [Chemical Weapons Convention](https://www.opcw.org/chemical-weapons-convention/articles/)?  As far as I can tell that treaty doesn't require that the chemical weapons be used against another Contracting Party

Comment: @JasonBaker - This is a State treaty. There are no specific obligations on individuals to comply. I suppose you could argue that the US govt were in breach, but you'd have a hell of a time proving it. Note that the convention's only sanctions for breach are to suspend the wronging party and to recommend to other nations sanctions that they consider appropriate; https://www.opcw.org/chemical-weapons-convention/articles/article-xii-measures-to-redress-a-situation-and-to-ensure-compliance-including-sanctions/

Comment: I don't know that you'd have a hard time proving it so much as you'd have a hard time doing anything about it; you're right that international courts don't have a ton of power over the US. But violating the CWC isn't a war crime in any case, so it's moot, I suppose

Comment: Why do you equate **war crimes** to violations of the Geneva Convention?  I think a lot of people would interpret **war crimes** has being defined by morality, not by some legal document.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I agree entirely. Many things are called "*war **crimes***" by people who don't understand that in order for something to be a crime, a law needs to have been broken. Otherwise it's just "*thing that I don't approve of*"

Comment: @Valorum I agree that there has to be a law before someone can break it but at the same time, weren't war crimes not a thing until after WW2 and then applied to the actions that happened in WW2?

Comment: @Durakken - One of the perks of being the winner in a conflict is that you get to impose justice on your opponents. Note that the Russians were ambivalent about the actual 'judicial process' given the crimes their own troops had committed. They favoured simply taking the Nazi high command out behind the bike sheds and shooting them.

Comment: @Valorum That's not justice. But that just goes to show that there not being a law against it doesn't make it not a war crime as set by that precident.

Comment: @Durakken - If you take retroactive legislation into account then *anything* could, theoretically speaking, become a crime. This question, however, is asking whether prima facie a crime was committed. The answer to that is "*no, not under international law **as it's currently comprised***".

Comment: @Valorum,  I don't think so,  and that's where morality and justice come in.   You just **chose** to interpret the question the way you did.

Answer (score 3):

War crimes are generally agreed upon between existing nations, and assume that each participant will agree and abide by them.  If not exactly agreed to by every single nation, they can at least be enforced by overwhelming majority of the planet at large.

(this is of course presuming that in the Stargate universe, the state of international law is roughly the same as it is in ours.  It's supposed to be Earth, so safe presumption, I think.)

Groups like the SGC and it's many evolutions are literally operating in a theatre of war that is left completely undefined by modern treaties.  I mean, there might be a section against space warfare, but since near-Earth orbit is the most that can be imagined by most normals, just the SGC's scope is completely out there.  Portal networks?  Parasitic infiltration?  Planetary bombardment?  No convention of war was ever considered with these things on Earth.

Even if they had been, no alien government that the SGC was hostile with is going to sit down and sign on to such an agreement either.  The weapons you cite the SG orgs for are the very things many aliens *want* to use against us (and in some cases, do).  Given that, I'd think it's extremely unlikely that anyone on Earth would attempt to hold most teams accountable for failing to apply Earth rules of war to an interstellar conflict that wasn't abiding by those moral standards to begin with and in which 99% of the time we were outgunned.

That's not to say that sometimes some morally questionable things happen - that bioweapons civilization that was going to virus everyone to death, the one that was tricked into opening a wormhole to a black hole and never heard from again, they had civilians, right? - but the likelihood of international law of war being applied is pretty low.